# Uploading an Xcode 5 app to an iOS 8 phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I just had a simple question. I was hoping to update my iPhone 5c to iOS 8 but I have been worrying about something, so I haven't done it yet. I worry that when I update to iOS 8 then I won't be able to put my apps from Xcode 5 on my iPhone (with iOS 8) anymore. This is because I have seen that when you try to put a swift app  on a phone with iOS 7, it doesn't work. Please let me know if this is true or not. Thanks!

Comment: Huh? This is really confusing? What is an Xcode 5 app? What does Swift have to do with this? If you've been using Xcode 5, you are not programming in Swift. And why aren't you using Xcode 6 by now?

Answer (score 2):

<s>You are correct to be worried. Once you update your phone to iOS 8 you will no longer be able to install & debug an app on it from Xcode 5.1. You could still build an .ipa manually and install it to your phone using an iTunes, as long as you build the iOS app using an AdHoc Provisioning Profile. If you update to iOS 8, Apple is kinda forcing you into Xcode 6.</s>
UPDATE:  rmaddy's comment is correct. You can build/install/debug from Xcode 5.1.1 to an iOS 8 device as long you've installed Xcode 6 and used it with the iOS 8 device.

Comment: Not perfect since it is incorrect. Xcode 5 can absolutely debug apps on a device with iOS 8. I did it for months. The only requirement is that Xcode 6 must be used with the device once, then Xcode 5 will work the device just fine.

Comment: @rmaddy is correct. Apparently I just needed to let Xcode 6 fully index the symbol info on my iPhone 5s (with iOS 8.0.2) and now I can build/install/debug an iOS 7.x SDK app from Xcode 5.1.1.